# Multiple if statements inside create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to pass two if methods `@result` and `@subscription_result` inside a create action. I first want to pass the `@result` successfully and then the `@subscription_result`

How do I correct the following create action in order for it to work???

```
def create

    @result =.....

     if @result.success?
      puts @result.customer.id
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'success'

    @subscription_result = .......

    if @subscription_result.success? 
      puts @subscription_result.susbcription.id

    else
      redirect_back( fallback_location: (request.referer || root_path),
                 notice: "Please try again!")
    end
  end
```

Comment: Why you need such thing? Why not check like `if @result.success? && @subscription_result.success?`.

Comment: You want to redirect to 2 places at once?? How do you expect that to work exactly? *"Of course, people do go both ways. That's the trouble. I can't make up my mind."* - Scarecrow [Wizard of Oz]

Comment: I need this first `puts @result.customer.id` from the `@result` in order to create the `@subscription_result`

Comment: `puts` inside a Rails controller is generally pretty useless. It's best to use `Rails.logger.debug` instead.

Comment: You do not need to `puts` anything to make anything work. `puts` outputs to `$stdout` and returns `nil` I cannot see how this has anything to do with your `@subscription_result`. Additionally, as soon as the redirect action fires the method exits. Maybe you need to fill in the *"......."* to clarify what you are talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly here is a simplest dumb solution:

```
def create
  @result =.....
  @subscription_result = .......

   if @result.success? && @subscription_result.success?
    puts @result.customer.id
    puts @subscription_result.susbcription.id
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'success'
  else
    redirect_back( fallback_location: (request.referer || root_path),
               notice: "Please try again!")
  end
end
```

Or something like that:

```
after_action :subscription_result, only: [:create]

def create
  @result =.....

   if @result.success? 
    puts @result.customer.id
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'success'
  else
    redirect_back( fallback_location: (request.referer || root_path),
               notice: "Please try again!")
  end
end

private

def subscription_result
  @subscription_result = .......
  puts @subscription_result.susbcription.id if @subscription_result.success?
end
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Max L.  sorry I didn't clarify this in the description, bur I first want to pass the `@result` successfully and then `@subscription_result`

Comment: @Theopap So do you need some actions after redirecting?

Comment: Correct. How can I wright this inside the def create method in order for the `@subscription_result` to work as well???

Comment: @Theopap you can use callback after_action as well https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/after_action and create appropriate method in your controller. If it's the correct direction I can write example for you if you give more code

Comment: @Theopap glad to help you!